# Excel function isn't working even when it was used several times before in the same document

Tags: excel

I'm studying for a test using Excel to help me in the book's questions. So, column A has the question number, column B is my answer and column C is the correct answer. In column D, I check if A equals B and assign 1 or 0 to it, so I just sum these values and see how many questions I answered correctly.

Here's a screenshot of my Spreadsheet.
[image]

I did this for all the 4 chapters, always duplicating the sheet, erasing the column B and C, and answering again. But, in chapter 5 and 6, this isn't working anymore.

Here's another screenshot, but now of Spreadsheet 5
[image]

I don't know whats going on here, or what I might be missing. I tried in Microsoft Excel 2016 (MacOS) and Google Spreadsheets (current screenshots), but the results are the same. I also try to force the column type to text and using the =EXACT() function, but it also returns false.

Answer (score 1):

after a few cups of coffee and 10 minutes of relaxing, I figured out.

I was copy/pasting the correct answers from PDF to Excel, and for some reasons, the answers in chapter 5 and 6 were coming with an extra space in the end of the line.

I solve it by using the =TRIM() function.

I deeply apologize for creating this topic and greet everyone who migh be reading.

Comment: I tried recreating your problem but couldn't. Thanks for posting the update.